# Непонятная ошибка при использовании keyup в jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Итак, есть форма с полями. В этой форме 2 поля обязательны к заполнению, причем одно поле должно содержать число от 1 до 99, а второе от 400 до 15000. Если при заполнении в полях прописаны подходящие данные показываем кнопку далее:

```
<img src="continue.png" alt="next" style="display: none;" id="next_kar" />
```

если что-то не так - прячем её. Вроде все просто.

Сделав обработку 1 поля таким образом на jquery я обрадовался - все работает как надо:

```
$('#karniz_asp').keyup(function(){
                    var karniz_asp_cnt = $('#karniz_asp_cnt').val();

                    if(karniz_asp_cnt > 0 && karniz_asp_cnt < 100) {
                        $('.karniz_asp_cnt_error').css('display','none');
                        $('#next_karniz_asp').css('display','block'); // Показываем кнопку продолжить
                    } else {
                        $('.karniz_asp_cnt_error').css('display','block');
                        $('#next_karniz_asp').css('display','none'); // Прячем кнопку продолжить
                    }
                });
```

и для второго поля прописал аналогично:

```
        $('#karniz_asp_dlina').keyup(function(){
            var karniz_asp_dlina_cnt = $('#karniz_asp_dlina').val();

            if(karniz_asp_dlina_cnt > 399 && karniz_asp_dlina_cnt < 15001) {
                $('.karniz_asp_error').css('display','none');
                $('#next_karniz_asp').css('display','block'); // Показываем кнопку продолжить
            } else {
                $('.karniz_asp_error').css('display','block').html("Длина должна быть от 400 до 15000мм.");
                $('#next_karniz_asp').css('display','none'); // Прячем кнопку продолжить
            }
        });
```

И оказалось, что для второго поля показ/сокрытие кнопки уже почему-то не работает!
Попробовал для первого поля убрать строки:

```
$('#next_karniz_asp').css('display','block');
$('#next_karniz_asp').css('display','none');
```

и для второго поля все чудесным образом заработало.

Вопрос, почему возник конфликт? Как в моем случае правильно сделать?
Почему если прописать

> $('#next_karniz_asp').css('display','block');
> $('#next_karniz_asp').css('display','none');

только в одном блоке $('#karniz_asp_dlina').keyup(function(){ });, все работает. А если добавить этот код во второй блок $('#karniz_asp_dlina').keyup(function(){ }); во втором блоке уже не работает?
Прошу помощи.

Comment: `#karniz_asp_dlina` не является дочерним для `#karniz_asp` ?

Comment: Можете выложить код на jsFiddle?